# Send file from a string in memory, but still incorporate etag functionality

Tags: node.js, http, express, browser, etag

I have a cached a file in memory. As far as I know, this is basically how etags are used by the server:

```
const fileInMemory = '...';

if(fileHasChanged()){
   res.status(200);
   res.write(fileInMemory);
   res.end();

else{
   res.status(304);
   res.end();
}
```

Does anyone know how to actually implement etagging? How do I compared the etag header from the request with the fileInMemory string? Is it just bytes?

I believe `res.sendFile()` and those methods are responsible for generating the etag info, so I might have to dive into the source.

I believe most of the relevant code is in here:
https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js

although I haven't figured out where `req.fresh` comes from:
https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L206

Comment: also, when I call res.end() I assume the encoding will be UTF8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity tags are opaque strings precisely to enable the server to implement them by any means it may desire, as long as it meets the requirements of [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232): in particular, if the payload changes at all, even in one insignificant byte, a strong entity tag must also change.

Servers that don’t know the nature of the payload typically use a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of the payload. In your example, you could (pre)compute `sha256(fileInMemory)` and use it (or some part of it) as the entity tag.

Servers that **do** know the nature of the payload use a variety of other tactics, such as checking the version of the payload as stored in some backend database. In your example, if your program has some associated version number, and `fileInMemory` never changes within one version, that version number might work as an entity tag.

By the way, note that the entity tag must always be wrapped in double quotes: so

```
ETag: "9c314d58"
```

and not

```
ETag: 9c314d58
```